# query wordpress database

Tags: wordpress

I have a table in the same database as my wordpress install. What is the correct way of querying it the "wordpress way" ? I know I can use mysqli and that is what I usually do. But I am sure wordpress has it's own standard and perhaps classes to do this.

thanks

Comment: Do you *need* to query the database? Are you sure it can't be done with prebuilt functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class) class? There is an example documented on wordpress.org and it goes like this:

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
```